# Probema de concurrencia con hebras en cola FIFO

Tags: c++

Tengo que hacer un problema del tipo productor-consumidor. El caso es que se debe de poder consumir en la sección crítica con mas de una hebra, mientras que escribir solo se debe de poder con una, aunque hay varias de estas también.
Osea, debes especificar en tiempo de ejecución cuantas hebras Productoras y Consumidoras quieres, luego deben de rellenar-consumir en un vector de 10 casillas 40 items... no se si me estoy explicando bien pero bueno. El error que me da es e siguiente:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Invalid argument
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Eso cuando eligo tener más de una hebra de cada, con 1 hebra consumidora y 1 productora no me da problemas

EL código es el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <random>
#include "Semaphore.h"

using namespace std ;
using namespace SEM ;



//**********************************************************************
// variables compartidas
const int TAMANIO_VECTOR = 10;
int primera_libre = 0;
int primera_ocupada = 0;
Semaphore ocupadas = 0;
Semaphore libres = TAMANIO_VECTOR;
Semaphore solo_1_escritura = 1;
int buffer[TAMANIO_VECTOR] = {0};


const int num_items = 40;   // número de items

unsigned  cont_prod[num_items] = {0}, // contadores de verificación: producidos
          cont_cons[num_items] = {0}; // contadores de verificación: consumidos


//**********************************************************************
// plantilla de función para generar un entero aleatorio uniformemente
// distribuido entre dos valores enteros, ambos incluidos
// (ambos tienen que ser dos constantes, conocidas en tiempo de compilación)
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

template< int min, int max > int aleatorio()
{
  static default_random_engine generador( (random_device())() );
  static uniform_int_distribution<int> distribucion_uniforme( min, max ) ;
  return distribucion_uniforme( generador );
}

//**********************************************************************
// funciones comunes a las dos soluciones (fifo y lifo)
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

int producir_dato()
{
   static int contador = 0 ;
   this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::milliseconds( aleatorio<20,100>() ));

   cout << "producido: " << contador << endl << flush ;

   cont_prod[contador]++ ;
   return contador++ ;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

void consumir_dato( unsigned dato )
{
   assert( dato < num_items );
   cont_cons[dato] ++ ;
   this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::milliseconds( aleatorio<20,100>() ));

   cout << "                  consumido: " << dato << endl ;

}


//----------------------------------------------------------------------

void test_contadores()
{
   bool ok = true ;
   cout << "comprobando contadores ...." ;
   for( unsigned i = 0 ; i < num_items ; i++ )
   {  if ( cont_prod[i] != 1 )
      {  cout << "error: valor " << i << " producido " << cont_prod[i] << " veces." << endl ;
         ok = false ;
      }
      if ( cont_cons[i] != 1 )
      {  cout << "error: valor " << i << " consumido " << cont_cons[i] << " veces" << endl ;
         ok = false ;
      }
   }
   if (ok)
      cout << endl << flush << "solución (aparentemente) correcta." << endl << flush ;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

void  funcion_hebra_productora(  )
{
   for( unsigned i = 0 ; i < num_items ; i++ )
   {
            if(primera_libre == 10)
                primera_libre = 0;

      int dato = producir_dato() ;

        sem_wait(libres);
            sem_wait(solo_1_escritura);
            buffer[primera_libre] = dato;
            primera_libre++;
            sem_signal(solo_1_escritura);
        sem_signal(ocupadas);

   }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

void funcion_hebra_consumidora(  )
{
   for( unsigned i = 0 ; i < num_items; i++ )
   {
            if(primera_ocupada == 10)
                primera_ocupada = 0;

      int dato ;
      sem_wait(ocupadas);
            dato = buffer[primera_ocupada];
            primera_ocupada++;
            sem_signal(libres);

      consumir_dato( dato ) ;
    }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
   cout << "--------------------------------------------------------" << endl
        << "Problema de los productores-consumidores (solución FIFO)." << endl
        << "--------------------------------------------------------" << endl
        << flush ;

  int numero_E = 0;
    int numero_L = 0;

    cout << "Introduce el número de hebras escritoras y lectoras, respectivamente: " << endl;
    cin >> numero_E >> numero_L;

    //Declaración de los vectores de hebras.
    vector<thread> vector_escritura;
    vector<thread> vector_lectura;

    thread escritura(funcion_hebra_productora);
    thread lectura(funcion_hebra_consumidora);

    //Lanzamos las hebras

    for(int i = 0;  i < numero_E; i++)
        vector_escritura.push_back(move(escritura));

    for(int i = 0;  i < numero_L; i++)
        vector_lectura.push_back(move(lectura));

    for(int i = 0;  i < numero_E; i++)
        vector_escritura[i].join();

    for(int i = 0;  i < numero_L; i++)
        vector_lectura[i].join();

   test_contadores();
}
```

Comment: Veo que [te ha lanzado una excepción](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error). Toda excepción no capturada aborta el programa. ¿Has probado añadir bloques `try`-`catch` en tu código?